# $_POST inside query PHP

Tags: php

I have a $_post with a value that I need to put inside a PHP query. have tried alot of different ways, but cant get it to work.

Ideas ?

```
$result = $xpath->query('/stickers/sticker[id=2]/text');
```

I need to change `[id=2]` to this `$_POST['textBoxID']`

Comment: [Strings](http://php.net/string) and [String Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Take a look at http://php.net/operators.string and you solve this problem. Please, do some searching before asking it on SO. More information in [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will `$_POST['textBoxID']` just be the numerical value? if so you can do this:

```
$result = $xpath->query('/stickers/sticker[id='.$_POST['textBoxID'].']/text');
```

Or if `$_POST['textBoxID']` will be the whole id=x do this:

```
$result = $xpath->query('/stickers/sticker['.$_POST['textBoxID'].']/text');
```

Read more here: http://php.net/operators.string

Comment: Its a numeric value. Worked like a charm... had missed the dots .
Thank you so much. appreciated

Answer (score 1):

You need to use double quotes or concatenation. Single quotes cause your variables to be taken as literals. Double quotes will allow them to be interpolated.

```
$result = $xpath->query("/stickers/sticker[$_POST[textBoxID]]/text");
```

or

```
$result = $xpath->query("/stickers/sticker[{$_POST['textBoxID']}]/text");
```

or

```
$result = $xpath->query('/stickers/sticker['.$_POST['textBoxID'].']/text');
```

Comment: or use `query('/strickers/sticker[$_POST[textBoxID]]/text');`

Answer (score 1):

---

You want either a

```
$thePost = $_POST['textBoxID'];
$result = $xpath->query('/stickers/sticker'.$thePost.'/text');
```

or

```
$thePost = $_POST['textBoxID'];
$result = $xpath->query('/stickers/sticker[id='.$thePost.']/text');
```